# Is it allowed in Islam to touch the feet of elders?

Tags: sharia, practical-islam, belief

I would like to know if touching the feet of elders is allowed in Islam.

Some people, even elders who have performed Hajj and pray five times a day, believe that children should touch the feet of elders/Parents and seek their blessings.

I believe that one should never bow/bend over except in front of Allah. This almost equals to a Sajdaah which is a very big sin as one should never do Sajdaah to anyone else except for Allah.

Please correct me and provide me with correct info with reliable sources of information (Hadith, Fatwa, etc.)

Comment: I think that your question is not related to Islamic law ..!!
Because touching the hand or foot for the elderly, parents,scholars is usually in some Muslim countries, and not bow (Sajdaah ) or glorification, but a matter of respect and appreciation

Comment: this should more to cultural pass downs rather than religious.

Answer (score 7):

There is general rule in islam, that we should Never Ever imitate Kuffar in any way. And touching the feet is integral part of hinduism. So based on the hadith of not imitating Kuffar we have to abstain from touching feet of elders by all means.

2nd view is that we have to do, what prophet Muhammad told us to do, otherwise everything added new to islam is an innovation and every innovation leads to hellfire. So as none of the sunnah tells us to do this act, so we should also stay away from it.
(Above vies are my own views, and i am not a scholar, just learning islam)

For scholarly reference: http://www.islamhelpline.net/node/9141

And Allah know the best

Comment: +1 Good solid answer. May Allah help you! :)

Answer (score 2):

> Narrated 'Umar bin Al-Khattab (May Allah be pleased with him): I heard Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) saying,
>   "The reward of deeds depends upon the intentions and every person will
>   get the reward according to what he has intended. ([Bukhari:1](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/1))

Respecting elders is a noble value also emphasized by Islam. Different cultures may have different manifestations for it. As long as it does not violate any principle of Islam it cannot be criticized.

Therefore, touching elder's feet with the intention of respect is acceptable. Even the Hindus who do it do not have an iota of polytheistic feelings for their elders. However, you may want to find your own proper way of doing it so that it does not seem to relate with shirk in any way.

My advise in this matter "Rather then thinking about the people to judge your deed let Allah Almighty judge it".

Comment: Kindly refrain from touching feet of elders, its not allowed in islam, here is fatwa of scholar: http://www.islamhelpline.net/node/9141

Comment: @Farhan Brother no where in the mentioned fatwa a clear sentence "not to kiss or touch feet"(in reference to hadith or ayat) is mentioned. So how can it be forbidden by just reading a fatwa. Thorough reading needed.

i found a detailed note on this as well.
Link: http://www.cifiaonline.com/kissingofhandsfeet.htm

Comment: actually there is a risk of imitation of kuffar. thats the reason Best is to avoid it, it is clearly explained in the link i shared.
but if you want to put yourself at risk, and also want others to be at risk as well, so its your choice... i prefer to just LEAVE any doubtful matter, to be at no risk of doing a Major sin or biddah

Comment: Brother religious matters are Bidah related so dont confuse this with any religious matter like that. I also shared the link that has great detail on it.

Dont worry Brother its not a risk if what you know what your doing with clear conscious of not making it relate to Shirk/Kuffar. Because its not you who has to judge at the day of judgement its Allah Almighty The Most Beneficent and the Merciful.

Answer (score 0):

One thing allah knows better.
next are few questions I would I like to ask.
our prophet wore different kind of dress which was a part of dressing at that time.
if sunnah is following the life style of prophet why are men wearing t-shirt jeans and ties.
see a religion teaches us to judge what is right and what's wrong.
islam thought it perfectly trough Quran .
thing is bowing down to take blessing .we know vl respect so vl bow down not bcoz of anyother means.
why make things complicated .
it's not compulsory but it's not a sin either.

Answer (score 0):

Allah knows better that what are your thinking, Intentiion or Niyah while touching the feet of your elders. I agreed with [Farhan](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/12456/28288) that its resembles to Hinduism. But what i would say is every person have their own ways for expressing love for their parents or elders and someone who love. Allah knows your Niyah that are you doing sajida or paying respect to elders. If you are kissing your mother feet while bow before her then its doesn't straight forward means that you are doing shirk or doing sajida. Allah knows your intentions well. May Allah guide us to the straight path. JazakAllah

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this issue it is very simple to understand,if we could remember the time when yakub alaihissalam and his family met his son Yusuf after a Long-term of separation.what happened was that (Allah says fa karru lahu sujjadah) they bowed to him.then Yusuf alaihissalam told his father saying that this is the meaning of the dream I had when I was young now the almighty God makes it true. So in this regard the sajdah they did to him was not the same with the one we are doing in our daily prayers rather it was just their traditional way of respect at that time.w allahu a'alam...

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please consider adding evidences to support your claims and see [answer].

Answer (score -2):

Ibn Maajah (1853) and al-Bayhaqi (14711) narrated that ‘Abdullah ibn Abi Awfa said: When Mu‘aadh ibn Jabal came from Syria, he prostrated to the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him), who said, “What is this, O Mu‘aadh?” He said, I went to Syria and saw them prostrating to their archbishops and patriarchs, and I wanted to do that for you. The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said, “Do not do that. If I were to command anyone to prostrate to anyone other than Allah, I would have commanded women to prostrate to their husbands. By the One in Whose hand is the soul of Muhammad, no woman can fulfil her duty towards Allah until she fulfils her duty towards her husband. If he asks her (for intimacy) even if she is on her camel saddle, she should not refuse.”

Comment: This is not addressing the question which is asking should Muslims touch the feet of elders.

Answer (score -5):

Farhan Allah's lovable :  I know a thing which is nor a wadoo is accepted by lord nor a namaz until you gain a perfect niyaat (emotion ) which is necessary you to prepare yourself for sajda or bow for blessings or love. Where as lord says sajda is only for me but he didnt said this same for the "love " part...